# setting up grunt/gulp for backend

Tags: node.js, automation, gruntjs, gulp

I'm building a node.js RESTful server, and I'm looking for a tool which can automate processes like  Grunt/Gulp do for the front-end.

Can you please suggest me what Grunt/Gulp tool I can you for this purpose?

Comment: You can use both. What exactely do you want it to do?

Comment: When I got a look over grunt plugins, I saw that more or less everyone were for frontend (concat, minify, uglify...) I don't need these tasks. What I wish to have, at least, is a task like grunt serve, which starts my server and after lunches the unit test on it

Comment: So what exactely are you looking for?

Comment: I edited prev comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grunt is a **task tool**. You can  use it for *anything* you want.

It depends on your workflow desires.

You can find a lot of plugins  for working on Node.js apps e.g.:

[grunt-contrib-nodeunit](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-nodeunit) for unit testing

[grunt-express-server](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-express-server) for running a server

And more...